# How can I change color of button's background

Tags: java, android, xml

I have many buttons in my calculator app. I am testing with only one button to start, that buttons id is "one" and should change colour when I click the <kbd>blue theme</kbd> button. I have tried following methods:

```
blueTheme = (Button) findViewById(R.id.blueTheme);
blueTheme.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        one.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(175, 144, 202, 249));
        one.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(/*hex code here*/));
        one.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

    }

});
```

Nothing seems to do anything. I am trying to change the colour of the button in one activity via an option in another activity. Here's actual button `one`:

```
one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.one);
one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        result.append("1");
    }
});
```

xml code of `one` in activity_main.xml:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/one"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#CCCCCC"
        android:text="1"
        android:textColor="#FF6600"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp" />
```

Idea is that there will be a option in another intent where I can change colors of calculator, but testing on one button fails, can't proceed. Thank you for your time.

Comment: In the First page you are choosing some colors and applying the colors for the button  in second activity right?

Comment: where is blueTheme button?? in the same activity as your button one??

Comment: @Shiriram yes you are right, frist some color is applied then I am applying another color from another activity.
@user3091574, blueTheme button is in different activity as my button `one`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the click from one activity cant get through to the other activity unless you pass it over.

**In the activity with the blue theme button**

```
blueTheme.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //NOTE: Where I've put MainActivity that should actually be the name
        //      of whatever activity this code is nested in
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OtherActivity.class); //use your real class name
        intent.putExtra(OtherActivity.EXTRA_COLOR, Color.BLUE);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

});
```

**In your OtherActivity.class**

```
public class OtherActivity extends Activity {

    public static String EXTRA_COLOR = "EXTRA_COLOR";

    public void onCreate(...) {

        View one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.one);

        //NOTE: if you add singleTop to this activity in the manifest
        //      you might need to do this on onNewIntent

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (intent.hasExtra(EXTRA_COLOR)) {
            int color = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_COLOR, Color.WHITE);
            one.setBackgroundColor(color);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: In my OtherActivity.class I am getting these errors:
Multiple markers at this line
 - The method getIntExtra(String, int) in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments 
  (String)
 - Color cannot be resolved

and in my activity with blueTheme button I am getting these errors:

Multiple markers at this line
 - The constructor Intent(new View.OnClickListener(){}, Class<MainActivity>) is 
  undefined
 - The constructor Intent(new View.OnClickListener(){}, Class<MainActivity>) is 
  undefined

Comment: You just have to supply what default value to return and make sure this is the activity. I'll update answer

Comment: @ShahbazTalpur For the first error, try removing Color.valueof around the getIntExtra(). For second error, you have to use new Intent(MyCurrentActivityName.this, ActivityToBeStarted.class); for constructing the Intent

Comment: David is correct, Color isnt an enum so valueof was wrong, you need the other two changes i made though - the second param for get int extra (which is the default value/color) and the class name in the intent - my answer has already been updated so you can see

Comment: Hey thanks! It worked now, only one issue, I wan't to use hex code for color because default aren't enough

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
// If you're in an activity:
yourButton.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
// OR, if you're not: 
yourButton.setBackgroundColor(yourButton.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
```

Comment: in both I am getting error at `R.color.red` color cannot be resolved.

Comment: Go to resource -> values -> colors.xml and define your color like :  <color name="DarkRed">#9b1717</color> then use R.color.DarkRed

Comment: There's no colors.xml in values

Comment: create one: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>  <color name="DarkRed">#9b1717</color> </resources>

Comment: This doesnt address the actual question

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set background color without using a pre-defined color resource, do it like so

```
one.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFF0000); // Red
one.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00FF00); // Green
```

Here, 0xFF00FF00 is equivalent to #ff00ff00 (#aarrggbb)

Comment: @ShahbazTalpur Oh, for changing color in another activity, Nick's answer is the correct one. Go for it.